# Scraping table contents using Requests and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, python-requests

Python/Webscraping Beginner so please bear with me. I'm trying to grab all product names from [this URL](http://www.rakuten.com/sr/searchresults.aspx?qu)

Unfortunately, nothing gets returned when I run my code. The same code works fine for most other sites but I've tried dozens of variations and I can't make it work for this site.

Is this URL even scrapable using Bsoup? Any feedback is appreciated.

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'http://www.rakuten.com/sr/searchresults.aspx?qu'
payload = {'q': 'Python',}

r = requests.get(url % payload)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
titles = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.findAll('div.productscontainer a[href^=/prod]')]

for t in titles:
    print(t)





import bs4
import requests

url = 'http://www.rakuten.com/sr/searchresults.aspx?qu'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
titles = [td.text for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'searchlist'})]

for t in titles:
    print(t)
```

If this formatting is correct, is the JS for sure preventing me from pulling anything?

Comment: You can edit the code in your question, no need to put that into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your string formatting likely is wrong. Look at this:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.rakuten.com/sr/searchresults.aspx?qu'
>>> payload = {'q': 'Python',}
>>> url % payload
'http://www.rakuten.com/sr/searchresults.aspx?qu'
```

I guess that's not what you want. You should look up how string formatting works in Python, and then come up with a proper way to construct your URL.

Secondly, that "search engine" makes heavy use of JavaScript. Probably you will not be able to retrieve the information you want by just looking at the initially retrieved HTML content.